# Is there a limit to the amount of cells a range object can hold?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a worksheet with roughly 300'000 rows of which a portion needs to be deleted.

I populate an array with row numbers, and perform a delete procedure for the rows in that array:

```
Sub Start()
'...

b = 0 
ReDim arr(b)

For i = LRow To 2 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, "L").Value = "" then
        ReDim Preserve arr(b)
        arr(b) = i
        b = b + 1
    End If
Next i

.Range("A" & Join(arr, ",A")).EntireRow.Delete

'...
End Sub
```

With the code above, `arr` ends up containing some 68'000 row numbers.

On the line that ought to delete these rows, I get the error

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

This also occurs when I try to select these, instead of deleting them.

Taking a portion of the output from the `Join` function performs as expected, such as:

```
.Range("A" & "2465,A2457,A2432,A2428,A2410,A2405,A2376,A2372,A2358,A2354").EntireRow.Delete
```

What causes the code to fail? Is there a limit on the `Range` object I am unaware of?

Comment: Tim why don't you insert the whole sheet into the array and then clear the first column on each row that matches your criteria, finally just remove duplicates by the first column (if there are on duplicates on the first column). Will be faster than deleting a big amount of rows. Or also, get the count of the rows to be deleted, redim another array and fill it from the initial one skipping the ones you don't need to paste it back to the sheet.

Comment: Fair enough @Damian, that indeed sounds like a faster method. I am however still interested in finding out why my code fails

Comment: You have anywhere a `with`-statement that you don't show? Else the  `.Range`-Syntax will fail

Comment: @FunThomas Yes, I omitted part of the code. Like I said, the last mentioned code runs without issues, the problem seems to be related to the `Join` function

Comment: I think there's a 255 character limit in a `Range` string reference.

Comment: Could be what @BigBen says, another idea is building a `Union()` inside the loop (avoiding the array) and then delete it all at once.

Comment: Completely agree with @Damian, don't use a `String` reference in this case, use a true `Range` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [workaround named range character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000533/workaround-named-range-character-limit)

Comment: I strongly encourage the both of you to write that as answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way:

```
Sub Start()
    '...

    Dim DeleteRange As Range

    For i = LRow To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "L").Value = "" Then
            If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRange = .Cells(i, "A")
            Else
                Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, .Cells(i, "A"))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    DeleteRange.EntireRow.Delete

    '...

End Sub
```

Thought trying your way, it should work as you say with:

`.Range("A" & "2465,A2457,A2432,A2428,A2410,A2405,A2376,A2372,A2358,A2354").EntireRow.Delete`
As long as your range doesn't exceed 255 characters. If it doesn't just check what is the value for: `"A" & Join(arr, ",A")` maybe there is something wrong or missing.

Edit: Another way to do this

```
Sub Start()
    '...

    Dim arrData
    Dim j As Long

    b = 1

    arr = .UsedRange.Value
    ReDim arrData(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 12) <> vbNullString Then
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                arrData(b, j) = arr(i, j)
            Next j
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Next i

    .UsedRange = arrData

'...
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is significantly slower than my initial code. This may last a hundred times longer than the previous method

Comment: From a quick glance you're populating a new array with data from the old array, excluding rows with empty values in 'L'. In that case, should it not be `If arr(i,12) <> vbNullString Then`?

Comment: Yes indeed... My bad! I was just changing some logic but didn't pay attention to the main logic! :)

Comment: Added an approach combining the array method with deleting entire rows collected via `Union`. BTW well done +1)

Comment: Excellent, now that's 100 times faster than my previous code. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's a 255 character limit for a `Range` reference, which you've surpassed by leaps and bounds; specifically,

```
"A" & "2465,A2457,A2432,A2428,A2410,A2405,A2376,A2372,A2358,A2354..."
```

can only be a max of 255 characters.

This can be validated with a simple test:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim arr(1 To 40) As String
    Dim arr2(1 To 80) As String

    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = CStr(i)
    Next i

    For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        arr2(i) = CStr(i)
    Next i

    Debug.Print Len("A" & Join(arr, ",A")) ' returns 150
    Debug.Print Len("A" & Join(arr2, ",A")) ' returns 310

    Range("A" & Join(arr, ",A")).EntireRow.Delete ' works
    Range("A" & Join(arr2, ",A")).EntireRow.Delete ' fails
End Sub
```

`Union` or an array solution, as already proposed, are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative combining array Approach with Union function**

Looping through ranges via VBA is time consuming, deleting via `EntireRow` using Union is fast, so a combination of both instead of collecting all remaining column values seems to be a good approach:

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nonsens")
' assign column data to 2-dim array
  Dim v, lrow&: lrow = .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  v = .Range("L1:L" & lrow)                     ' start from top to get correct row numbers later
' check first empty cell
  Dim currRow&, delRng As Range
  For currRow = 2 To UBound(v)
      If v(currRow, 1) = vbNullString Then
           Set delRng = .Range("A" & currRow)
           Exit For
      End If
  Next currRow
' collect rest via UNION function
  For currRow = currRow To UBound(v)
      If v(currRow, 1) = vbNullString Then Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Range("A" & currRow))
  Next currRow
' delete entire rows in range set
  If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete

End With

End Sub
```